# PyAudio playing audio in Callback is choppy

Tags: python, audio, audio-playback

I'm using a Logitech usb headset ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000UXZQ42?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UXZQ42)) to record and playback audio.

I need non-blocking playback because I want the user to be able to control the playback.

Based on the examples from http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/ I've got recording working fine in calback mode.

Playback works nicely in blocking mode but the following code produces choppy distorted audio.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import time

CHUNK = 256
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'output.wav'

pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'rb')

def playingCallback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    data = wf.readframes(frame_count)
    return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)

stream = pa.open(format=pa.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
                 channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                 rate=wf.getframerate(),
                 output=True,
                 frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                 output_device_index=2,
                 stream_callback=playingCallback)

stream.start_stream()

while stream.is_active():
    time.sleep(0.5)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
wf.close()

pa.terminate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sound distortion is coming from your `while` loop. By calling the sleep function, you're telling your program do **nothing** for half a second, and then come back.

If we look at their [blocking example](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/), you can see they handle the loop differently:

```python
# read data
data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)

while len(data) > 0:
    stream.write(data)
    data = wf.readframes(CHUNK)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jacobm001. I had that thought but, in callback mode `stream.start_stream()` starts calling `playingCallback` in another thread. The `time.sleep(0.5)` is just keeping the main thread alive until the stream is done. Changing `0.5` to '0.1' or '1.0' has no effect on the 'choppyness' of the playback.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the chunk size argument to be 0.5-1 second.
I.E if you are playing at a 16000hz audio rate, set chunk size to 8000.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem. I checked the times of call_backs per second. It is about rate/chunks/2. I still do not know why it is half of rate/chunk. Have you figured out why?

I think I have found the reason. The chunk is too small which results in too frequent callbacks. Maybe due to the limited CPU power of Raspberry Pi. It will lose some chunks. You can make larger chunks, for example, 8192. It resolves my problem.